# Open PDF File and Perform Text Search Using excel vba

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

I need to develop a simple excel vba application to do some data validation.  I have excel files with employee information and I need to validate that information against the source document ( a pdf file(s)).  The information in excel is grouped by employee name.

Is it possible to write a VBA script that will open a specified pdf file, then allow the user to perform a search of the employee name so the pdf jumps to the appropriate employee page?   (Each employee has an individual page in the pdf document.) Once on the employee page the user would review the data, make any necessary edits to the excel file and then search for the next employee.

I believe I can use:

```
Sub NavigatePDF()

ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "c:\user\target.pdf"

End Sub
```

to open a pdf file, but I don't know how to issue a search from excel vba once I have the file open.

Can anyone offer any suggestions or point me to some useful resoucres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some additional research yielded an application written by Christos Samaras.  The tool uses excel vba to open a specified PDF and then highlight the provided search term.  Possibly the only downside is a requirement for Adobe PDF Pro - the code will not work with Acrobat Reader.

Here are [link](http://www.myengineeringworld.net/2014/05/pdf-search-through-vba.html) and code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindTextInPDF()

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'This macro can be used to find a specific TEXT (more than one word) in a PDF document.
    'The macro opens the PDF, finds the specified text (the first instance), scrolls so
    'that it is visible and highlights it.
    'The macro uses the FindText method (see the code below for more info).

    'Note that in some cases it doesn't work (doesn't highlight the text), so in those
    'cases prefer the SearchTextInPDF macro, if you have only ONE WORD to find!

    'The code uses late binding, so no reference to external library is required.
    'However, the code works ONLY with Adobe Professional, so don't try to use it with
    'Adobe Reader because you will get an "ActiveX component can't create object" error.

    'Written by:    Christos Samaras
    'Date:          04/05/2014
    'e-mail:        xristos.samaras@gmail.com
    'site:          http://www.myengineeringworld.net
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'Declaring the necessary variables.
    Dim TextToFind  As String
    Dim PDFPath     As String
    Dim App         As Object
    Dim AVDoc       As Object

    'Specify the text you wawnt to search.
    'TextToFind = "Christos Samaras"
    'Using a range:
    TextToFind = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PDF Search").Range("C5").Value

    'Specify the path of the sample PDF form.
    'Full path example:
    'PDFPath = "C:\Users\Christos\Desktop\How Software Companies Die.pdf"
    'Using workbook path:
    'PDFPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "How Software Companies Die.pdf"
    'Using a range:
    PDFPath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PDF Search").Range("C7").Value

    'Check if the file exists.
    If Dir(PDFPath) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Cannot find the PDF file!" & vbCrLf & "Check the PDF path and retry.", _
                vbCritical, "File Path Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Check if the input file is a PDF file.
    If LCase(Right(PDFPath, 3)) <> "pdf" Then
        MsgBox "The input file is not a PDF file!", vbCritical, "File Type Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next

    'Initialize Acrobat by creating the App object.
    Set App = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

    'Check if the object was created. In case of error release the object and exit.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Could not create the Adobe Application object!", vbCritical, "Object Error"
        Set App = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Create the AVDoc object.
    Set AVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

    'Check if the object was created. In case of error release the objects and exit.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Could not create the AVDoc object!", vbCritical, "Object Error"
        Set AVDoc = Nothing
        Set App = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    'Open the PDF file.
    If AVDoc.Open(PDFPath, "") = True Then

        'Open successful, bring the PDF document to the front.
        AVDoc.BringToFront

        'Use the FindText method in order to find and highlight the desired text.
        'The FindText method returns true if the text was found or false if it was not.
        'Here are the 4 arguments of the FindText methd:
        'Text to find:          The text that is to be found (in this example the TextToFind variable).
        'Case sensitive:        If true, the search is case-sensitive. If false, it is case-insensitive (in this example is True).
        'Whole words only:      If true, the search matches only whole words. If false, it matches partial words (in this example is True).
        'Search from 1st page:  If true, the search begins on the first page of the document. If false, it begins on the current page (in this example is False).
        If AVDoc.FindText(TextToFind, True, True, False) = False Then

            'Text was not found, close the PDF file without saving the changes.
            AVDoc.Close True

            'Close the Acrobat application.
            App.Exit

            'Release the objects.
            Set AVDoc = Nothing
            Set App = Nothing

            'Inform the user.
            MsgBox "The text '" & TextToFind & "' could not be found in the PDF file!", vbInformation, "Search Error"

        End If

    Else

        'Unable to open the PDF file, close the Acrobat application.
        App.Exit

        'Release the objects.
        Set AVDoc = Nothing
        Set App = Nothing

        'Inform the user.
        MsgBox "Could not open the PDF file!", vbCritical, "File error"

    End If

End Sub
```